# Creating Grid layout when clicked on nav tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a profile page like Instagram.

What I want is a 3 grid layout display of cards, to be divided in 3 numbers when viewed on Desktop with a gap of 10px, in mobile just one card visible and it should be responsible and fit to screen till 250px media width.

Let me know how can I do that. I also have a problem in removing the active class of nav tabs when clicked on other tabs.

Please check and let me know.

I tried the following:

```js
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]');
const content = document.querySelectorAll('[data-content]');

targets.forEach(target => {
  target.addEventListener('click', () => {

    content.forEach(c => {
      c.classList.remove('active')

    })

    const t = document.querySelector(target.dataset.target)
    t.classList.add('active');
    target.classList.add('active');
  })
})
```

```css
#main-profile {
  margin: 0;
  profile: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.profile-container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper-profile {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "intro details details details";
}

.wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-intro {
  grid-area: intro;
}

.wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-details {
  grid-area: details;
}

.wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-intro,
.wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-details {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: 10px;
}

.profile-header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.profile-header img {
  display: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.wrapper-profile-intro .profile-card {
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 300 !important;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper-profile-intro .profile-card .profile-image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.wrapper-profile-intro .profile-image img {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  object-fit: fill;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
}

.profile-card .profile-image span {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  background: #2afa6a;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.profile-card .profile-name {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile-card .profile-name h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.profile-card .profile-name p {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #818181;
  margin: 1px;
}

.profile-card .profile-page-stats {
  margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.25rem;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 300!important;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.profile-card .profile-page-stats .stats {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.profile-card .profile-page-stats .stats #followerCount,
.profile-card .profile-page-stats .stats #mediaCount,
.profile-card .profile-page-stats .stats #followingCount {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  color: #1d1d1d;
}

.profile-card .profile-page-stats .stats span {
  color: #818181;
}

.profile-card .profile-page-stats::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: -16px;
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

.profile-card .profile-details p {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.profile-card ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.50rem;
  margin-right: 45px;
}

.details-header nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-left: -40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.details-header nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.details-header nav ul li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.details-header nav ul li.active {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.details-header nav button {
  background: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.details-header nav button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.wrapper-profile-details .details-content {
  position: relative;
}

[data-content] {
  display: none;
}

.active[data-content] {
  display: block;
}

.card {
  min-width: 15rem;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 300 !important;
  position: relative;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper-profile {
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "intro" "details";
  }
  .wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-intro,
  .wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-details {
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
  .wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-intro {
    margin-bottom: -5px;
  }
  .profile-card .profile-page-stats {
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .details-header nav {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  .details-header nav ul {
    gap: 10px;
  }
  .details-header nav ul li.active,
  .details-header nav ul li {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .details-header nav button {
    margin-left: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main-profile">
  <div class="profile-header">
    <img src="img/6.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="profile-container">
    <div class="wrapper-profile">
      <div class="wrapper-profile-intro">
        <div class="profile-card">
          <div class="profile-image">
            <img src="img/4.jpeg" alt="profile-picture">
            <span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="profile-name">
            <h2>Umann Goswami</h2>
            <p><i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i><span> Basic member</span></p>
            <p>
              <p>Anna@xyz.com</p>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="profile-page-stats">
            <div class="stats">
              <strong id="mediaCount">56.7K</strong>
              <span>Media</span>
            </div>
            <div class="stats">
              <strong id="followerCount">56.7K</strong>
              <span>Followers</span>
            </div>
            <div class="stats">
              <strong id="followingCount">56.7K</strong>
              <span>Followings</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--profile-page-stats-->
          <div class="profile-details">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fab fa-pinterest"></i></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper-profile-details">
        <div class="details-header">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li class="active" data-target="#blogs">Blogs</li>
              <li data-target="#images">Images</li>
              <li data-target="#about">About</li>
            </ul>
            <button>Follow</button>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <!--details-header-->
        <div class="details-content
                ">
          <div data-content id="blogs" class="active details-content-boxes">
            <div class="card">
              abc
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              abc
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              abc
            </div>
          </div>
          <div data-content id="images" class=" details-content-boxes">
            123
          </div>
          <div data-content id="about" class=" details-content-boxes">
            12
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--details-content-->

      </div>
      <!--wrapper-profile-details-->
    </div>
    <!--wrapper-profile-->
  </div>
  <!--profile-container-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example using CSS Grid and media queries to achieve the desired layout:

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="card">Card 1</div>
  <div class="card">Card 2</div>
  <div class="card">Card 3</div>
  <div class="card">Card 4</div>
  <div class="card">Card 5</div>
  <div class="card">Card 6</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 250px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

.card {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

To remove the active class of nav tabs, you need to use JavaScript or jQuery to listen for the click event on the tabs and remove the active class from the current active tab and add it to the clicked tab. Here is a basic example using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.nav-tabs a').click(function() {
  $('.nav-tabs .active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```